# Show selectrionable dynamique drop-down list

Tags: java, list, javafx, dropdown, picker

I want generate a  selectionable dynamique drop-down list which contains a lot of values in JavaFX whith a JDK 1.8.
Each time the user write something, I keep just the value that include this substring and I display it.
When the user see what he wants, he can select it by a click.
I know that I should use listener on my TextField and what to do with my method but I don't know what Java Object I should use if it exists and I don't found it on internet.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a ComboBox with the property editable to true then use the listener and compare your list with the actual value.